# Dequeue Array of cells for UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a struct like this :

```
struct Elements {
 var name: String
 var cells: [UITableViewCell]
}
```

this struct is filled in another class with data, then passed to the UITableViewController, where I have an array of elements like this:

```
var elements: [Elements]
```

what I was wondering, if it's possible to dequeue the cells from this array to the UITableView, because when doing this it doesn't work :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
return elements[indexPath.section].cell[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: You should really not be retaining the cells directly.  Your data should be distinct from the UI implementation of it.  If you do this you lose all of the functionality for reusing cells that a `UITableView` provides.  For example if you have 10,000 elements in you list you have now created and retained 10,000 `UITableViewCells` where as you really only need the few on the screen (plus maybe a few extras) and this is what the `UITableView` handles for you.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I went with the approach of having the data and the identifier of the cell in the struct ( because I have 5 types of cells) , but when handling them in the tableViewController , I end up with too much code. That why I was wondering if it's possible to build the cell with the data then add it to the tableView

Comment: It is certainly possible but not advisable.  With any kind of scale you will start to run into issues.  With 5 types of cell it would be more advisable to have 5 sub-classes of `UITableViewCell` decide which one you need when dequeuing a cell and then pass the data structure to that cell sub-class to set up the cells own UI as it needs.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth is correct. You want to do it Apple's way, not your way.  This will save you a ton of grief, not only in this example, but in others.  Let Apple's routines provide you a cell, or a custom cell, in cellForRowAt, and you just populate that cell with what it needs to display.